# Looping through multidimensional associative arrays and outputting results

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, associative-array, multidimensional-array

Basically, I'm trying to loop through all the posts and find their appropriate tags. The $id variable is an array of all the post id's returned. So the first for loop should be finding all the tags for the posts and if there aren't any for that post set the tags to 0 (for $post_tags['THIS IS THE POST ID'])

It all seems to be fine for if there are no tags for a post and it will simply print 'No specified tags' once alongside with it (as expected). But, what seems to be happening is that the tags printed are all the tags from the appropriate post PLUS the ones from the previous posts returned. It seems to be adding onto what has been returned already.

I honestly don't see why it's doing this and considering there is no error coming up I find it hard to address. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, avatar FROM members WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")){                          
// Get the posts tags
if($tgs = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE post_id = ?")){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++){
        $tgs->bind_param('i', $id[$i]);
        $tgs->execute();
        $tgs->store_result();
        $tgs->bind_result($tag);
        while($tgs->fetch()){
            $tags[] = $tag;
        }
        if($tgs->num_rows > 0){
            $post_tags[$id[$i]] = $tags;
        }else{
            $post_tags[$id[$i]] = 0;
        }
    }
    $tgs->close();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++){             
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$by[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($username, $avatar);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo '<ul class="f_ul_subject" style="margin-top:3px">
                    <li class="f_cat_subject" style="font-size:10px;line-height:12px;">';
                            for($j = 0; $j  < count($post_tags[$id[$i]]); $j++){
                                if($post_tags[$id[$i]] != 0){
                                    echo '<a class="post_tag" href="http://localhost/Site/NetPerry/forum/search.php?v=' . $post_tags[$id[$i]][$j] . '&amp;tags=true">
                                            <span>' . $post_tags[$id[$i]][$j] . '</span>
                                        </a>';
                                }else{
                                    echo 'No specified tags';
                                }
                            }
                    echo '</li>
                </ul>                                                       
            </li>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `$tags[] = $tag;` is a problem

Comment: Of course, too localized question "find me a bug in my code".

Comment: Thanks for the reply it has stepped me in the right direction and it seems to works now. Though there was no obligation to reply, if you didn't feel the "find me a bug in my code" was appropriate for this site you didn't have help. Though, thank you that you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tags[] = $tag;` is filling up the array without ever emptying it. This is why the tags keep piling up. You can solve this by declaring the array empty before the fetch loop, like this:

```
$tags = array();
while($tgs->fetch()){
...
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer was accepted as it won't be of any help

Comment: @YourCommonSense care to elaborate ? I don't see why

Comment: Well may be I am wrong. I didn't think there would be a distinct query for the each post

Comment: A prepared query can be reused as much as you like. Though I have to admit the code structure is a bit unusual.